# How to pass route data from an ActionFilterAttribute to an action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm routing users to a login-view if the session has expired, using an `ActionFilterAttribute`, like shown below.

Now, I want to keep the route data from the original request, so that I can route the user back to that view after logging in.

How can I send the original route data to the `Login` action method?

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public int? BranchId {get => HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("BranchId") as int?;}
    public string Admin {get => HttpContext.Session.GetString("Admin") as string;}

    public BaseController() {}
}

public class AdminOrBranchesAccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        if ((context.Controller as BaseController).Admin == null &&
            (context.Controller as BaseController).BranchId == null)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Login"
            }));
        }
    }
}

[AdminOrBranchesAccess]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    // Some stuff going on
    return View();
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use a redirect, then you either have to store that data in session or return it to the client and have the client send it back on the next request. This is an HTTP restriction, not an MVC restriction.

Comment: @KennethK. How would I store it in session? Is there some way to do it in one place for the whole application, or do I have to do it in each of my controller methods? I don't have access to `HttpContext` in the `OnActionExecuting`-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rediecting to previous action after login successfully, you need to provide return url for login action and set its value in `OnActionExecuting`.

1. Change `Login` method like below with parameter `returnUrl`

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
   {
       // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
       await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

       ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
       return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
   {
       ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
           // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
           var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
           if (result.Succeeded)
           {
               _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
               return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
           }
           if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
           {
               return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
           }
           if (result.IsLockedOut)
           {
               _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
               return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
           }
           else
           {
               ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
               return View(model);
           }
       }

       // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
       return View(model);
   }
   ```
2. `AdminOrBranchesAccessAttribute`

   ```
   public class AdminOrBranchesAccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
       {
           base.OnActionExecuting(context);

           if ((context.Controller as BaseController).Admin == null &&
               (context.Controller as BaseController).BranchId == null)
           {
               context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
               {
                   controller = "Home",
                   action = "Login",
                   returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.Path
               }));
           }
       }
   }
   ```